# How do I delete text before and after 1 character

Tags: notepad++, regex

For example I have:

```
Apple:123456789:pear
watermelon:57952161354:kfc
```

How do I delete the text that's before and after the ":" to get this:

```
123456789
57952161354
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^:]+:([^:]+):[^:]+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    [^:]+:      # 1 or more any character that is not colon followed by 1 colon
    ([^:]+)     # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not colon
    :[^:]+      # 1 colon followed by 1 or more any character that is not colon
$               # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1  # content of group 1 (i.e. the digits)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
123456789
57952161354
```

Comment: You're the best!